# How to control the access to a function based on the last access time using threads?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I want to control the access to a function based on the elapsed time since the last access.

For this purpose, I have implemented the following decorator, which works perfectly in a single thread execution:

```
import time

MIN_ELAPSED_TIME = 0.4
time_last_get = time.time()

def timingRequests(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        global time_last_get  
        elapsed_time_since_last_get = time.time() - time_last_get
        if elapsed_time_last_request < MIN_REQUEST_TIME: # not enough time has passed since the last request
          time.sleep(MIN_REQUEST_TIME - elapsed_time_last_request)

        # At this point, at least MIN_ELAPSED_TIME has passed since last get
        time_last_get = time.time()
        r = f(*args, **kwargs)
        return r
    return wrapper

@timingRequests
doGet()
```

I want to have n threads (2 for now) accessing this function AND take into account the time_last_get between threads. My problem is that each thread is waiting to execute doGet() based on its own previous execution of doGet()

I tried to use threading.Event() as a semaphore, threading.Lock() but still both threads are accessing the function almost at the same time.

The behaviour when using 2 or more threads is that every thread waits to execute doGet() based on the time_last_get of that same thread, instead taking into account the access of the other threads.

The behaviour that I want to achieve is the next one:

Thread-1: doGet()

Thread-2: Waits (if necessary) MIN_ELAPSED_TIME seconds passed since Thread-2 access

Thread-2: doGet()

Thread-1: Waits (if necessary) MIN_ELAPSED_TIME seconds passed since Thread-2 access

Thread-1: doGet()

Thread-1: Waits (if necessary) MIN_ELAPSED_TIME seconds passed since Thread-1 access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out what the problem was.

First, I did bypass the problem by using threading.Events() instances:

```
import time

MIN_ELAPSED_TIME = 0.4
time_last_get = time.time()
e = threading.Event()
e.set()

def timingRequests(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        e.wait()
        e.clear()
        global time_last_get  
        elapsed_time_since_last_get = time.time() - time_last_get
        if elapsed_time_last_request < MIN_REQUEST_TIME: # not enough time has passed since the last request
          time.sleep(MIN_REQUEST_TIME - elapsed_time_last_request)

        # At this point, at least MIN_ELAPSED_TIME has passed since last get
        time_last_get = time.time()
        r = f(*args, **kwargs)
        e.set()
        return r
    return wrapper

@timingRequests
doGet()
```

But I was still struggling to understand why this solution works, but not using the lock.

Well, the problem was this:

```
def timingRequests(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        with threading.Lock():
            # Code
```

Every thread reaching this part of the code was creating an (unlocked) instance of threading.Lock(), so the lock was not working as expected. The solution then is to create the lock outside the timingRequests function and use it this way:

```
lock = threading.Lock()

def timingRequests(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        with lock:
            # Code
```